# CakePHP - Problems with ErrorHandler not extending AppController

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I had been wondering why my error page caused certain pages of my site
not to render, but then I realized that it's because AppError extends
ErrorHandler instead of AppController.  This caused some variables
that I set in AppController's beforeFilter method not to be sent to
the view.  Since I can't access session variables from AppError, I
thought that I might be able to get away with using the classRegistry
to instantiate something that could and simply copying and pasting the
rest of my code from AppController's beforeFilter... but that isn't working, nor does it seem like a very elegant fix.  Does anyone have any clues as to what
would be the best way to approach this?  Thanks, David.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your AppError class has a controller instance.  You can call the beforeFilter manually:

```
<?php
class AppError extends ErrorHandler {
  function error404() {
    $this->controller->beforeFilter();
    parent::error404();
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In CakePHP 2, you can do something like this to achieve the same effect. In `app/Config/bootstrap.php`, add this line:

```
Configure::write('Exception.renderer', 'AppExceptionRenderer');
```

Then create a file `app/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php` with this code:

```
App::uses('ExceptionRenderer', 'Error');

class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {
    protected function _outputMessage($template) {
        $this->controller->beforeFilter();
        $this->controller->render($template);
        $this->controller->afterFilter();
        $this->controller->response->send();
    }
}
```

Described more generally here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#using-a-custom-renderer-with-exception-renderer-to-handle-application-exceptions

**Edit:** Updated link to point to correct location of the CakePHP 2.0 Book as of July 05, 2012.